# Should I store chat messages in the chat document or in separate documents in Firestore using Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, chat

I'm making a real time chat app in Flutter and I've come to a point when I have to decide how I want to store messages in Firestore. I have 3 collections in Firestore, `chats`, `users`, and `messages`.

[image: Firestore collections]

I'm currently storing every message as a separate document in the `messages` collection.
A message document looks something like this:

[image]

I'm storing the uid of the message sender and the id of the chat that the message was sent to, so later I can make query to Firestore like this:

```
  // messages is the collection reference
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getChatMessages(String id) => messages
      .orderBy('sentOn', descending: true)
      .where('sentTo', isEqualTo: id) // gets all the messages that were sent to the given chat id
      .snapshots();
```

However, this method isn't very good because of the number of reads or writes I have to do to work with my data in Firestore. Another big problem appears when I want to delete the chat and all of it's messages, as I would have to delete every message document separately and if I stored the messages in the chat document it would only be one delete call to Firestore. On the other side, earlier in another project when I stored all messages in a `Map`, I noticed that it would get quite slow at drawing the messages on the screen as their number increased.

What do you think? Which is the better option? Is there anything I missed or maybe another way to approach the problem? Please let me know.

Thanks. <3

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can approach this. One of the ways to do it is:

Store all messages of a particular chat as a sub collection in the chat document.

So you'll have to delete your message collection.

For example:

In the chat collection, if we have a chat document with ID "123", the we can store all the messages of that chat document as a sub collection under the chat document.

This will reduce your number of reads and writes, thereby making your application more performant and fast.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).